# Comparing occurrences of characters in strings

Tags: python, comparison

[code](http://codepad.org/PoHe9u1Y)

```
def jottoScore(s1,s2):

    n = len(s1)

    score = 0

    sorteds1 = ''.join(sorted(s1))

    sorteds2 = ''.join(sorted(s2))

    if sorteds1 == sorteds2:
            return n

    if(sorteds1[0] == sorteds2[0]):
        score = 1 
    if(sorteds2[1] == sorteds2[1]):
        score = 2
    if(sorteds2[2] == sorteds2[2]):
        score = 3
    if(sorteds2[3] == sorteds2[3]):
        score = 4
    if(sorteds2[4] == sorteds2[4]):
        score = 5

    return score


print jottoScore('cat', 'mattress')
```

I am trying to write a jottoScore function that will take in two strings and return how many character occurrences are shared between two strings.

I.E jottoScore('maat','caat') should return 3, because there are two As being shared and one T being shared.

I feel like this is a simple enough independent practice problem, but I can't figure out how to iterate over the strings and compare each character(I already sorted the strings alphabetically).

Comment: What do you mean by matching characters? Should the be at the same position in both strings? Without a clear definition of what you want it's impossible to tell how to solve your problem.

Comment: what should be the answer for "aat" and "maat" or "taa" and "mat"

Comment: It **appears** that the characters have to be the same, and in the same index, but the OP already said that the strings were being sorted, so maybe it just **appears** that they need to have the same index.  @tysonisasaint: please clarify.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on Python2.7+ then this is the approach I would take:

```
from collections import Counter

def jotto_score(str1, str2):
    count1 = Counter(str1)
    count2 = Counter(str2)
    return sum(min(v, count2.get(k, 0)) for k, v in count1.items())

print jotto_score("caat", "maat")
print jotto_score("bigzeewig", "ringzbuz")
```

**OUTPUT**

```
3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

in case they are sorted and the order matters:

```
>>> a = "maat"
>>> b = "caat"
>>> sum(1 for c1,c2 in zip(a,b) if c1==c2)
3
```

Comment: No need for the list-comprehension. Use a genexp: `sum(1 for c1,c2 in zip(a,b) if c1==c2)`. Note however that this is highly dependent on the order, e.g. if `a = "test"` and `b="est"` the answer is `0` and not `3`(which may or may not be what the OP wanted).

Comment: Nope. For 'mata' and 'caat', this won't give the right answer OP wants.@sberry

Answer (score 0):

```
def chars_occur(string_a, string_b):
    list_a, list_b = list(string_a), list(string_b) #makes a list of all the chars
    count = 0
    for c in list_a:
        if c in list_b:
            count += 1
            list_b.remove(c)
    return count
```

EDIT: this solution doesn't take into account if the chars are at the same index in the string or that the strings are of the same length.

Comment: Why do you need it recursively?

Comment: It will be an overhead but I think you can pas string_a[1:] as you go into recursion and the exit condition from the recursion should pe if not string_a or not string_b: return. There be made some more changes.. the for should be changed to a simple if to check string_a[0] in string_b... each return to the function must be retained so you can add the counts at the end.

Answer (score 0):

A streamlined version of [@sberry answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18073779/823942).

```
from collections import Counter

def jotto_score(str1, str2):
    return sum((Counter(str1) & Counter(str2)).values())
```